# Output Path in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I want to output my C# project into a user defined folder.
Therefore I tried the following:

**1. Setting the output path in the properties**

[Setting Output path in properties for all configs and any CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy7M7.png)

I built in Debug|x64 mode the C# project.

The solution contains a second project in C++ which has a config type of DLL. Goal is to use the DLL in C++ in my C# project.

**C++ Project properties**

[Property Page for C++ Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMTD7.png)

Here is the respective code for:

**C# Project**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll")]
        public static extern void HelloWorld();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HelloWorld();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**C++ Project**

```
#include <iostream>

// Expose function
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();

void HelloWorld()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

**The problem now is:**

- When I build both projects there are no errors.
- When running the project, the C++ DLL cannot be found. This, I found out is because of the incorrect build pathes.

  - Whereas the C++ correctly resolves the environment variables I set, the C# project doesn't. It creates folders named as the variable name itself, instead of building into the resolved path name.

**The build for the C++ file resolves correctly the output path**

[Output C++ build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aig4h.png)

**The build for the C# project doesn't**

[Output C# build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8owEb.png)

I just cannot figure out how to resolve this issue, but I am also fairly new to this. Can you help me out?

Regards

Sebastian

Comment: *"output path in Visual Studio Code for a C# project"* - but your screenshot shows output path in Visual Studio for C/C++ project. Instead of manually copying the DLL you should add a post build step.

Comment: Yes, I have included it and still it doesnt translate correctly. When I opened up the csproj xml, I see this output. Not sure where to start now

Comment: Everytime i build my project in c#, the output path is not being resolved and still writes the wrong path within the c# project folder but not in the folder as given in the output path

Comment: Are you sure you're changing the settings for the active configuration and platform not for some other configuration?